# How can I use WSGI 3.4 with Python 3.3.1?

Tags: apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I installed Python 3.3.1 and Apache 2.4.4 from source in Ubuntu 12.10.

When I built WSGI source code, it told me that:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

I don't know how to deal with it.
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Modify the generated Makefile and change '-lpython3.3' to '-lpython3.3m'. Then build again.